# Python Webscraping - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, text, attributeerror

I need some help in trying to web scrape laptop prices, ratings and products from Flipkart to a CSV file with BeautifulSoup, Selenium and Pandas. The problem is that I am getting an error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'** when I try to append the scraped items into an empty list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "C:/Users/folder/PycharmProjects/chromedriver.exe")
#flipkart website
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~cs-g5q3mw47a4/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&collection-tab-name=Browsing&wid=13.productCard.PMU_V2_7")


products = []
prices = []
ratings = []


content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
for item in soup.findAll('a', href = True, attrs={'class' : '_1fQZEK'}):
    name = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_4rR01T'})
    price = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_30jeq3 _1_WHN1'})
    rating = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_3LWZlK'})
    
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)
    

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': products,
                        'Price': prices,
                        'Rating': ratings})

    df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\folder\Desktop\webscrape.csv", index=True, encoding= 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.contents` or `.get_text()` instead `.text`. Also, try to care about NoneType :

```py
products.append(name.get_text()) if name else ''
prices.append(price.get_text()) if price else ''
ratings.append(rating.get_text()) if ratings else ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found ! The error was solved after replacing **.text** with **.get_text()**. Also the way to avoid another error **ValueError: arrays must all be same **length**** is to print(len()) to confirm whether the length of appended data to be passed into the Pandas dataframe.

In this case, the ratings variable was found to have len() of 0 in all iterations of the for loop, so they were not included in the dataframe, df. Below is the modified code:

```
#--snip--
    
#empty list to be appended later with webscraped items
products = []
prices = []
ratings = []

for item in soup.findAll('a', href = True, attrs={'class' : '_1fQZEK'}):
    name = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_4rR01T'})
    price = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_30jeq3 _1_WHN1'})
    rating = item.find('div', attrs={'class' : '_3LWZlK'})
    #append the info to the empty lists

    products.append(name.get_text()) if name else ''
    prices.append(price.get_text()) if price else ''

    #creating pandas DataFrame
    print(f"Products: {len(products)}")
    print(f"Prices: {len(prices)}")
    print(f"Ratings: {len(ratings)}")

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product Name': products,
                        'Price': prices})
     #sending the dataframe to csv
    df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\folder\Desktop\samplescrape.csv", index=True, encoding= 'utf-8')
```